# Instantiate std::atomic<> with a user-defined type UDT. If UDT has virtual function,l inkage will fail.Why?

Tags: c++, c++11

here is an example:

```
#include <atomic>
using namespace std;

struct udt
{
    int a;
    virtual int get() 
    {
        return a;
    }
};

main()
{
    udt y;
    atomic<udt> x;
    x=y;
}
```

compiling the program with gcc fails at the linkage stage,the error message is ***undefined reference to `__atomic_store_16'***. Removing the virtual keywork of udt::get() can fix this issue. I can't understand why udt cannot have virtual function when it is used to instantiate std::atomic<>

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic - I don't think a class with a virtual function is considered trivially copyable

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **[atomics.types.generic]/1** The template argument for `T` shall be trivially copyable...
>
> **[class]/6** A *trivially copyable* class is a class:
>   (6.1) — where each copy constructor, move constructor, copy assignment operator, and move assignment operator (15.8, 16.5.3) is either deleted or trivial...
>
> **[class.copy.ctor]/11** A copy/move constructor for class `X` is trivial if it is not user-provided and if:
>   (11.1) — class `X` has no virtual functions (13.3) and no virtual base classes (13.1)...

`udt` is not trivially copyable. Your program exhibits undefined behavior by way of passing a template argument to a template from the standard library, that violates the requirements of that template.